# uninstall software in command line

Tags: command-line, uninstall

I install a software in commande line from [this](ftp://genome.crg.es/pub/software/geneid/geneid_v1.4.4.Jan_13_2011.tar.gz) source  and I did : `tar -zxvf geneid_v1.4.4.Jan_13_2011.tar.gz` and `make` but I put it in my Download folder, so I would like to install it in a more proper way, in another folder.

So i did `make clean`, Is it enough ? I have just to `rm` the folder and that's all ?

Thanks

Comment: Especially [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) answer contains install/uninstall instructions for all possible software.

Answer (score 0):

If you just ran `make`, then it is ok to just delete the folder...

Comment: And if I did make install or ./config ?

Comment: if you did `./configure`, that's ok (that's just preparation for make)... If you did `make install`, than full uninstall may be hard or almost impossible...

Comment: really ? It's not possible to unistall a programm ?

Comment: Make install just copies some files in system directories, it is hard (to impossible) to find all of them... You can try running `make uninstall`, but it might not be implemented... If it is not, the only suggestion is to study the Makefile a deleted all files manually